# Visual Basic Custom Progress Bar Not Moving

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner in VB, and I tried making a progress bar from two panels, but the front one isn't moving. Code:

```
Public Class Startup
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Front.Width < Me.Width Then
            Front.Width = Front.Width + 10
        End If
        If Front.Width = "1366" Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Login.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have Timer1.Interval and Timer1.Start properties anywhere?

Comment: Opps, silly me! The timer was diabled and not strated. Oh well... Thanks! However, for some strange reason, it does not want to show Login... I did change in properties the "Shutdown Mode", but to no effect...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use the winforms progress bar?  Have you put a breakpoint in your code to see if it gets hit?  Have you tried stepping through your code?

Comment: I've added that as a answer, if that helped you to solve your problem please Mark it as an Answer of your question and press Up Arrow to up-vote the answer.

Comment: Please see my last comment, edited.

Comment: a few thing i noticed here: 1: `IF Front.Width = "1366" THEN` Width is usually a int while "1366" is a string. You might get some trouble here. 2: If  you increase Front.Width by 10 you might just skip 1366 and go from 1360 to 1370. so checking for 1366 will never trigger. please check these 2 things

Comment: sorry, index, that didn't change anything

Comment: any code in the  Login.load event?

Comment: Your line `If Front.Width = "1366" Then` is comparing an integer to a string. You are not meant to do that - if you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then Visual Studio will point out mistakes like that for you.

Comment: Andrew, I fed that already. Didn't work. Anyway, new problem now...

Comment: Begging for upvotes is almost a sure way to get more downvotes.

Comment: @user265658 you never told us what happens when you place a breakpoint to your If statement? Even tho we asked a couple of times.

Comment: I fail to see how if something didn't work... It can cause a new problem? Obviously something changed or you would not have a new problem!

Answer (score 0):

What INDEX said is absolutely correct!

You should be testing against a number not a string

> If Front.Width = 1366 Then

Then note his/her second point!
You are incrementing in steps of 10, you will pass by 1366 without hitting it!

Therefore your should change the IF statement to

> If Front.Width >= 1366 Then